Nissan J10 violently shake/wobble when accelerating
EDIT: I finally found the problem! I replaced the front right CV axle, and the issue is now resolved. The mechanics told me it was most likely the intermediate bearing located in the middle of the CV axle that was causing this issue.
For the past six months, my car (Nissan J10) has been shaking violently at high speeds when accelerating. Here is the most detailed description I can provide:
The shaking generally occurs (though not always) above 100 km/h under load (such as an incline), and only during acceleration. When coasting or releasing the gas pedal, the shaking stops. The vibrations can be felt under the seat and beneath my feet but not from the pedals or the steering wheel. I have also noticed that the shaking, although less intense, happens when I slow down over a speed bump and then accelerate hard to regain speed.
I have already consulted several garages, and they have found nothing wrong with the CV axle and suspensions. My tires are brand new and balanced, my injectors are in good condition, and the silent block/motor mount are also fine (according to mechanics).
I have not noticed any clicking noise when I turn the steering wheel.
I am at a loss for what to do next. The problem seems very much like an issue with a bad CV axle or drive shaft. Could I have encountered incompetent garages? Is it possible that the problem is not visually identifiable?
I was thinking of blindly replacing the CV joints one by one, although the main drive shaft would be the most expensive to replace. Is there any way to differentiate symptoms for the drive shaft vs cs axle?
Here is a video I recorded during the shaking (sound at maximum to hear it clearly).
And here’s all the parts for that specific car.
BRAND: NISSAN J10E
PROD. DATE: 2007-2010
BODY: VISIA
ENGINE: M9R (2.0 DCI 150)
AREA: EUC
DRIVE: 4WD
TRANS: F6 (automatic, not CVT)
Thank you in advance to anyone who can offer advice!

You may have bad engine mounts that allow the driveline to move when under load. This will affect the cv joint angle and cause vibration.

This. The fact that the vibration only occurs under power suggests engine mounts. Anything wrong with the suspension, axles, wheels, or alignment would likely still vibrate when off the throttle.

I finally found the problem! I replaced the front right CV axle, and the issue is now resolved. The mechanics told me it was most likely the intermediate bearing located in the middle of the CV axle that was causing this issue.
